# Write conditional for a "city not found" error

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

I'm studying and building a weather journal app for a project using openweathermap.

When I write a zip code that doesn't belong to the country of my API, the console logs "cod:404 message:city not found", but I don't know how to display this to the user. I know that I need to write a conditional with an alert (wrong zip code!) before my postData code but I'm stuck here...

```js
function action(e){
    const postalCode = document.getElementById('zip').value;
    const feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
    console.log(newDate);
 
    getTemp(baseUrl,postalCode, apiKey)
    .then(function (data){
         if(/*Message error*/){
            alert('Wrong zip code, try again!');
        }
        //Route
        postData('http://localhost:8000/addData', { date: newDate, temp: data.main.temp, feel: feelings})
    .then(function(){
        //User Interface
        updateUI()
        })    
    })
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uBXI.png)

Comment: Could you show me your `gettemp` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the response is an object containing `cod` and `message`, you can check `if (data.cod === 404) {`
Then show your alert.
Note that you need to `return;` or put the `postData` in the `else`, otherwise it still would be executed after the alert shows

Problem with @Yehr59 's answer, is that the `getTemp` probably won't throw an error, therefore it doesn't reach the `.catch` function. So in the `.then` you can perform the check I mentioned above in this answer.

You would have something like this:

```js
getTemp(baseUrl,postalCode, apiKey)
    .then(function (data){
         if(String(data.cod) === '404'){
            alert('Wrong zip code, try again!');
        } else {
            //Route
            postData('http://localhost:8000/addData', { date: newDate, temp: data.main.temp, feel: feelings})
        }
```

I also wrapped data.cod around `String`, so it's always a string. We can't compare

```
"404" === 404 // false
```

Edit: Another way is to modify your `getTemp` function so that it would `throw` an error if the response code is 404, then you know once the .then is called, it's successful, and if the .catch is called, you'll handling an error

Answer (score 0):

you can just use like this :

```
getTemp(baseUrl,postalCode, apiKey)
.catch(function (error){
    alert('Wrong zip code, try again!');
    console.log(error);
})
.then((data) => {
    postData('http://localhost:8000/addData', { date: newDate, temp: data.main.temp, feel: feelings})
      .then(function(){
        //User Interface
        updateUI()
    })    
})
```